# What is the non-flattened Scala Vector of Sets: (1 to 2).flatMap((1 to 3).toSet.subsets(_))?

Tags: scala, flatmap

I can see `(1 to 2)` is a Range.

```
scala> (1 to 2)
res20: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2)
```

I can see the Sets from this Iterator.

```
scala> (1 to 3).toSet.subsets
res0: Iterator[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = non-empty iterator

scala> (1 to 3).toSet.subsets.mkString("\n")
res1: String =
Set()
Set(1)
Set(2)
Set(3)
Set(1, 2)
Set(1, 3)
Set(2, 3)
Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Finally, here is a Vector of Sets when flattened. What is it when not flatted? How can I display it?

```
scala> (1 to 2).flatMap((1 to 3).toSet.subsets(_))
res19: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Vector(Set(1), Set(2), Set(3), Set(1, 2), Set(1, 3), Set(2, 3))
```

Comment: If you run `(1 to 2).map((1 to 3).toSet.subsets)` you get `IndexedSeq[Iterator[Set[Int]]] = Vector(<iterator>, <iterator>)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `flatMap` with `map` would give an unflattened list of subsets of different sizes:

```
(1 to 2).map((1 to 3).toSet.subsets(_).toVector)
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]]] = Vector(
//   Vector(Set(1), Set(2), Set(3)),
//   Vector(Set(1, 2), Set(1, 3), Set(2, 3))
// )
```

Note that since [`subsets`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#subsets(len:Int):Iterator[This]) returns an `Iterator[Set[A]]`, `toVector` converts the `Iterator`s into nested `Vector`s.